# Panel or group box in MaterializeCSS?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, materialize

Is there something like Bootstrap panels in MaterializeCSS?

Bootstrap panels here:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_panels.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to a Bootstrap `panel` would be called `card-panel` in [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/cards.html).

Example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
<!--Card Panel-->
<div class="card-panel">
    <span class="black-text">A Basic Panel</span>
</div>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Panel and well are abonded by bootstrap in their upcoming v4.0

[Bootstrap Developer Explains Here..](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/)

Basically Cards are much better replacements of panels and you can get same results in them.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s4">
        <div class="card darken-1">
             <div class="card-content   ">
                 <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                    <p>I am a very simple card. 
                       I am good at containing small bits of information.
                       I am convenient because I require little markup to
                       use effectively.
                     </p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-action">
                  <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                  <a href="#">This is a link</a>
             </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

however if you like the look and feel of bootstrap panel with different title background and different body background then you'll have to stick with bootstrap not materializecss